# Creating SVN repository server with XAMPP on windows

Tags: eclipse, svn, repository, xampp

For last 3 days I am struggling in setting up my SVN server. I tried several ways and tools but I found always some issue and bug all the files.

I am planning to use the following tools for this project.

1. For Server and database - XAMPP (Comes with APACHE and MySql)
2. Version control server - subversion-1.6.16
3. Version control client - tortoiseSVN
4. IDE is Eclipse

Following are my queries
1. Is the above combination of tools and softwares is perfect for my project?
2. Is there any open-source software which provides all the above functionalities combined?
3. If anybody of you has already done such kind of project, could you please share with me which are the correct version of softwares I should use to get it worked error free.

If anybody can provide solution for below I can carry on with my current setup also.

My Error Message from server for current configuration : I tried to setup the svn-win32-1.6.16 with my XAMPP installation by copying the two moduels mod_dav_svn.so and mod_authz_svn.so to my apache modules directory and changed the httpd.conf file with Loadmodules of these the so files and set the location also for these. But when i start the server in error logs I get error message like this - "httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 136 of C:/xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load C:/xampp/apache/modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: The specified module could not be found."

Following are pre-conditions and configurations prior to this error
Location of SVN - C:/SVN/svn-win32-1.6.16
Location XAMPP - C:/xampp/

Changes in httpd.conf file

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

and for location

```
# Enter this location in your browser to access the repository
<Location /repos>
    DAV svn
    SVNPath c:/SVN/svn_repos
</Location>
```

I have created the repository here - C:/SVN/svn_repos

Comment: see here http://svn.spears.at/. These are common tools used by dev team, but no one can really tell the suitability for you.

Comment: You accepted my answer but you didn't upvote it, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the above combination of tools and softwares is perfect for my
>   project?

That is impossible to answer, because:

a) we don't know what your project is
b) nothing is perfect

But it is definitely an ok combination of tools. If I were you I would not use XAMPP but Zend Server CE instead! You get a nice web GUI for most php configuration needs.

> Is there any open-source software which provides all the above
>   functionalities combined?

No. These tools are maintained for various target audiences and the combination you're asking for wouldn't make much sense in a bundle.

But of course your IDE (Eclipse in this case) integrates nicely with these tools. 'Integrates' means it plays together, doesn't mean it comes bundled with these things.

> If anybody of you has already done
>   such kind of project, could you please
>   share with me which are the correct
>   version of softwares I should use to
>   get it worked error free.

I used to have such a combination (now I'm on Zend Studio with Zend Server CE) and there is no problem with it. **The problem is that you're trying to do something unnecessary and wrong.**

1. If you're using XAMPP, you're on a Windows machine, using .so extensions wouldn't do any good at all, Windows needs .dll extensions.
2. Why do you want to load such extensions anyways? You don't need those in order to get it all working.
3. Where are your repositories? Only if you want to host your own repositories do you need to run your own server. If that is the case, look at [VisualSVNServer](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/). You just install it, no need for integration with anything.
4. If your repositories are on a location in the net (more likely) you don't need an SVN server, you just need the client. In that case you're ready to go, no need for php extensions. You can checkout repos, commit, export, branch, tag, etc. From within Eclipse or in your file system with TortoiseSVN.

Try it and get back here, if you still experience problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your to-the-point replies. I really liked it. I will definitely follow your suggestions. By the way I am trying to setup a server where I can host an website for my company. The website uses database also. So I choose the XAMPP which comes with it. But now I wanted this server to host my source code repository also for my development teams. So I just tried to extend the functionalities by using DLLs for SVN. I would like hear your valuable advice on my above requirement. By installing Zend Server CE or VisualSVNServer will it solve all these necessity? Please advice.